# How to send GET/POST request from App Service in VNet_1 to Function App in VNet_2?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

I have an App Service that sends a POST request to the URL of the Function App. However, the Function App does not receive the request.

My current setup is the following:

**Function App**

- Vnet Integration: Vnet_2
- Private Endpoint's Virtual network: Vnet_2
- RouteAll enabled

**App Service**

- Vnet Integration: Vnet_2
- Private Endpoint's Virtual Network: Vnet_1
- RouteAll enabled

When users log in to my website served on App Service, it should send a POST request to the Function App.

However, I get a timeout, nothing happens. I suspect the POST request does not reach the Function App as it does not get triggered (HttpTriggered Function).

Networking-wise, what adjustment should happen for the requests to be able to flow from Vnet_1 to Vnet_2 and vice versa?

I tried setting up another private link and updated the Function App and App Service as follows:

**Function App**

- Vnet Integration: Vnet_2
- Private Endpoint's Virtual network: Vnet_2
- Private Endpoint's Virtual network: Vnet_1
- RouteAll enabled

**App Service**

- Vnet Integration: Vnet_2
- Private Endpoint's Virtual Network: Vnet_1
- Private Endpoint's Virtual network: Vnet_2
- RouteAll enabled

...however, this did not solve the issue. The Function App still does not get triggered.

The only solution so far is if I open up the network and then everything works. But this is a no-go.

Comment: Thinking of Peering the 2 networks, would it resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Private endpoint is used to access the app service or the function app while the VNET integration is used to control the outbound traffic.

As the private endpoint of App Service is linked with Vnet_1 and the VNET integration is done with Vnet_2, the **VNET peering needs to be done from Vnet_1 to Vnet_2** so that app service can access the resources in the Vnet_2

If the VNET peering is done from Vnet_1 to Vnet_2, the app service should be able to send a POST request to the URL of the function app whose private endpoint is linked with Vnet_2